# Driver priority during boot in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, touchpad, priority

I've Windows 8 installed on my laptop. It's pretty old, so old that it's touch-pad is not natively supported in Windows 8. Whenever I boot/restart it, all the applications and other less needed services load first, costing close to a minute, or little more. Only after this, Synaptics' driver for the touch-pad is loaded.

Now this behavior annoys and bugs me. It's like you've to wait 2 minutes and stare at the screen all along until everything is finished loading so that the touch-pad driver can finally be loaded.

How can I change the priority of these applications/services in Windows so that Windows recognizes touch-pad driver is more important than the other applications/services and thus load the driver before them?